# server large jiffies during boot(Calibrating delay loop...)

Tags: high-load, timestamp, dmesg

The server behaves abnormal, I checked the dmesg log , found the jiffies is very large during boot, between Detected cpu and Calibrating delay loop..

reboot the server does not solve the problem. shutdown and cool down for a while then restart it may fix .
this problem seems to be random .

arch: x86_64
linux kernel :
Linux 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cpu:

```
processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 45
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 0 @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 2400.221
cache size      : 10240 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 4
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 38
initial apicid  : 38
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 4799.93
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

dmesg log:

```
[    0.000000] Checking aperture...
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] Memory: 16430212k/18874368k available (4405k kernel code, 2121024k absent, 323132k reserved, 7781k data, 1356k init)
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:262400 nr_irqs:1560 16
[    0.000000] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] allocated 134217728 bytes of page_cgroup
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.000000] Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.004000] Detected 2400.221 MHz processor.
[18014398.509485] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4800.44 BogoMIPS (lpj=9600884)
[18014398.509491] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[18014398.697153] kdb version 4.4 by Keith Owens, Scott Lurndal. Copyright SGI, All Rights Reserved
[18014398.697392] Security Framework initialized
[18014398.697409] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[18014398.698801] Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes)
[18014398.702395] Inode-cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[18014398.703874] Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
[18014398.704061] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[18014398.704066] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[18014398.704082] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[18014398.704085] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
```

anyone has good suggestions? thanks very much !

link: [wired dmesg output and high cpu load](https://serverfault.com/questions/732750/wired-dmesg-output-and-high-cpu-load)?

Comment: update: when I unplug the machine,and push the power button to reboot ,everything goes normal,  so perhaps it is because of the bad timer on the motherboard.